# is it possible to convert direct link to torrent?

Tags: utorrent

**how to convert direct link to torrent ?**

when you want to create `torrent` file, you just select your file from your computer and torrent file has made but i want to make torrent file from a `direct link`.

is it possible ? if yes , what's the procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Burnbit](http://burnbit.com/) is a free web service that does just that.  Here's a bit more [background information and commentary](http://torrentfreak.com/burn-any-web-hosted-file-into-a-torrent-with-burnbit-100913/) on the service, and the [official FAQ](http://burnbit.com/faq).

I've never used the service, but was also curious about your question.  I stumbled across Burnbit when researching it.

Comment: tanks a lot :D, it works

Comment: burnbit is dead for so long.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative: https://superuser.com/a/1243795/320611

Answer (score 3):

There is a new service called [URLHash](http://www.urlhash.com/), now that Burnbit is dead.

I have used it personally and it works great. Even better than Burnbit (RIP).

Answer (score 2):

To make a torrent file, you need to actually be physically hosting the file on your machine. You cannot remotely link to a webserver or something as the contents of a torrent file. That'd be fairly unethical too I think since you're leeching off someone elses bandwidth.

You need to have the files within the torrent on your machine, and they must be locally accessible by the Client/Server to use them.

**tl:dr No, you cannot do that.**

Answer (score 1):

BurnBit is a Web Service and too buggy doesn't even support smaller file. I recommend you to use Utorrent Web Seed For This.

Simple make a torrent.

[image: Screenshot of new torrent with web seeds]

Comment: can you gime me the address ?

Comment: its in Utorrent, make torrent<web seed option<put your link

Comment: without `source` ( address of file in your computer) it wouldn't work, if you can do it, explain exactly it in your answer . because i couldn't do that

Comment: I do it on VPS, so i have source there.