# How do I create a torrent from direct link?

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, vps

I want to download a video from web but downloading directly may be interrupted. So, i am trying to find a way that I can download it through torrent, like what Burnbit.com can do. 
However, I have read from this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/399310/is-it-possible-to-convert-direct-link-to-torrent/402017#402017?newreg=9ce98a9bc0ec479287c2e592d4c755cc) that it can also be done using uTorrent.
They told that you will just simply create a torrent in uTorrent and put the link on the "Web seeds" option. About the directory of file, there is one who said that he did it on VPS.
I am about to try it but the problem is I don't know what to do with the directory of file and how to do it on VPS. That's what I want to know. And, does it really work?
(I can't comment on that thread because I am just using a new account. So , i posted it as question here.)
Thank you for incoming responses.